# Android, calculating SHA-1 hash from file, fastest algorithm

Tags: android, performance, file, hash, sha

I have a problem with SHA-1 performance on Android. In C# I get calculated hash in about 3s, same calculation for Android takes about 75s. I think the problem is in reading operation from file, but I'm not sure how to improve performance.

Here's my hash generation method.

```
private static String getSHA1FromFileContent(String filename)
    {

        try
        {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            //byte[] buffer = new byte[65536]; //created at start.
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            int n = 0;
            while (n != -1)
            {
                n = fis.read(buffer);
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    digest.update(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            }
            byte[] digestResult = digest.digest();
            return asHex(digestResult);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how can I improve performance?

Comment: what's the size of the file you are reading ?

Comment: Try running your code without `asHex(..)` method (just return byte[]).

Comment: I'm using 6MB file, removing asHex(..) haven't helped :/

Comment: Donald_W, what kind of device do U use?

Comment: Since people still upvote my question you should use the implementation from my question or DevProd's answer. My main issue was using very old device (ADP1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested it on my SGS (i9000) and it took 0.806s to generate the hash for a 10.1MB file.

Only difference is that in my code i am using BufferedInputStream in addition to the FileInputStream and the hex conversion library found at:

http://apachejava.blogspot.com/2011/02/hexconversions-convert-string-byte-byte.html

Also I would suggest that you **close your file input stream** in a finally clause

Comment: This link is broken as of 11/10/15.

Comment: Link is broken in 2017.

Comment: Dam this should be down voted just for posting an external url instead of writing answer here.

Comment: Link is broken in 2021

Comment: The original source code of the plagiarised `HexConversions.java` file can be found on the original author's website (which unfortunately appears to now require authentication to access). An archived version (latest from 2017) can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171115213622/http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/io/HexConversions.java

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would [use the JNI like this guy did](http://code.google.com/p/android-thomson-key-solver/source/browse/trunk/android/jni/sha1.c?spec=svn158&r=96) and get the speed up that way. This is exactly what the C interface was made for.